# How to make Vim autocomplete a word based on words already found in the buffer?

Tags: vim

> How to make Vim autocomplete a word based on words already in the buffer?

How can I make Vim autocomplete words, based on words already found in the buffer, just like it is possible with Emacs (M-%)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<C-n>` and `<C-p>` will complete what is in *all* buffers. `<C-x><C-n>` and `<C-x><C-p>` will do exactly what you asked for and only give completion for tokens in the current buffer. However, there are a lot of completion options in Vim. To learn more about them, I would suggest reading the help section on them `:help ins-completion` (this is called insert mode completion).

A few other completion options in Vim are `<C-x><C-f>` to complete file paths and `<C-x><C-l>` to complete entire lines.

Comment: I didn't knew about file paths and entire lines, it is so cool!

Answer (score 5):

C-x C-n and C-x C-p do that in insert mode (next and previous)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a plugin with an auto popup :  [neocomplcache plugin](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache.vim)

> It provides keyword completion system by maintaining a cache of keywords in the current buffer. neocomplcache could be customized easily and has a lot more features than the Vim's standard completion feature.

[image: with auto popup window]